# Database Compatibility: Building a database to support apps across multiple OSs

Tags: android, ios, database, windows-8, operating-system

I know very little about developing apps/software, so please forgive my ignorance in advance.

I would like to develop a proprietary digital dictionary (using my own definitions, not taken them from other websites). To do this I will need to build a database, that will contain multiple definition for each words and many examples of their use.

Eventually, I would like to use this database to build apps for Android, iOS, and Microsoft operating systems. My question is, for example, if i use SQL Server 2012 will I be able to use this same database when I try to make an app for Android? If not are their any neutral open source database systems like XAMPP which would work across all three operating systems?

*Extra Information*: I would like the apps to pull definition from a database embedded inside the app, not from an internet server; this way, users will be able to use the dictionary without an internet connection.

Comment: You cannot run an MSSQL on Android. And you cannot ship it with a Program on Windows unless the customer has an SQL Server themselves. There are license issues involved. I suggest you use sqlite instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no.

SQL Server works exceptionally well with ASP.NET, and with ASP, you can write a webservice to grab the data off the server and deliver it to ANY platform in a readable format (XML, JSON, or whatever).

Getting data from the server would then be simply a matter of consuming the webservice from whatever platform.  Any of the mobile devices, any desktop implementation you decide to make, or even if you just gave your webservice a web page so the webservice could be consumed by browsing to a web address.

From there, all you need to do to make the data accessible offline is to setup the application to download the entire database the first time and store it locally (and from here, you could simply use sqlite).  From then on, it could simply look for updates.  Keep in mind, however, mobile devices have limited storage capacity.

Comment: So, I could use SQL Server to make a skeleton website using ASP.Net and then it would be a matter of getting the different apps to pull the information from the website?

Comment: Also, would this be safe? I might have to work years to develope the defintions and examples; I wouldn't want someone to make a prettier app and steal my definitions. (Perhaps a copyright would solve this problem).

Comment: No.  You use ASP.NET to make the skeleton webservice.  It doesn't have to have a website.  ASP.NET talks to the SQL server (and is ideally hosted on the same machine even) to get the data the person consuming the webservice asks for.  You can get the data via GET or POST requests.

Comment: When consuming a webservice, you are sending arguments.  For example, what word are you looking for the definition of?  That'd be an argument.  You could add to the list of arguments some sort of password or some sort of security so that the webservice could only be consumed by someone providing the correct password.

Comment: Do you think that SQL Server would be a good choice? I can get the software free from my university, and there are several tutorial on Lynda.com. My main worry is that in the long run using a WISA solution stack might be very expensive in the long run, what do you think?

Comment: I'm not a database expert.  I don't know.  I also don't know enough details about exactly what you're doing.  If you're using SQL Server, I'd definitely use ASP.NET for the webservice.  But you could just as easily use MySQL for the database and PHP for the webservice.  I'm not really an expert on database or webservice implementation... I just have experience from the app-end consuming this sort of stuff.

Comment: I will look into the cost issue a little more, but this is a good start. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can make the comms between app and website more secure by using https (besides just a password, which could be sniffed by a hacker)

Comment: @JimmyJackson See auspicious99's comment.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a common database that can be embedded locally in your app, as opposed to accessing a remote database, then [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org) is probably a good choice. It is fully supported in iOS and Android. It has a C API as well as others so it should also work with other mobile environments.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and this link, I am checking it out now.